# webpack jquery ajax rails 5 InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, webpack, ruby-on-rails-5

I use Rails 5.1 + webpack 
When I include jQuery to my project with

```
 plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        'jQuery': 'jquery',
        '$': 'jquery',
        'global.jQuery': 'jquery'
    })
  ]
```

And try to use jQuery.ajax PUT, POST, or DELETE requests e.g.

```
var that = this;
$.ajax({
  url: navigator_item.url,
  method: 'DELETE',
  success: function(res) {
   ...
  }
});
```

I get `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`.

But, when I include jQuery with next line in `app.js` file

```
import $ from 'jquery'
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $; // lazy fix if you want to use jQuery in your inline scripts.
```

and this in shared.js

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
        'jquery': 'jquery/src/jquery'
    }
  }
```

`jQuery.ajax` works fine.

Is there a way using `jQuery.ajax` when you include jQuery as a plugin?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` has nothing to do with jQuery.

You have to pass an `authenticity_token` parameter with all your `PUT`, `POST` and `DELETE` requests.

To do that you can usually fetch it from the header with `$('[name="csrf-token"]')[0].content`

So your request would look something like:

```
var that = this;
$.ajax({
  url: navigator_item.url,
  data: { authenticity_token: $('[name="csrf-token"]')[0].content},
  method: 'DELETE',
  success: function(res) {
   ...
  }
});
```